# how to print the classes specified in the @SuiteClasses using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, junit

Test.class

```
package a.b.c;
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({abc.class,bcd.class,cde.class})
public class Test{}
```

Load funtion

```
void load(){
Class.forName(a.b.c.Test);
//code
}
```

my output should be like

```
abc.class
bcd.class
cde.class
```

Now how do i print the classes specified within @Suite Classes?
Is there any other way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption, that you have designed a class level annotation: `@SuiteClasses`, 
The classes can be read and printed by the below-mentioned methods.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
// TODO import


Class<Test> obj = Test.class;
if(obj.isAnnotationPresent(SuiteClasses.class)){
       Annotation annot = obj.getAnnotation(SuiteClasses.class);
       SuiteClasses suiteCls = (SuiteClasses) annot;
       //TODO
}
```